# Why does Drupal\\Core\\Config\\UnmetDependenciesException occur on install?

Tags: installation, virtual-machine

I tried to Install drupal on a Ubuntu 22.04.2 VM.
I route the guest via NAT to my host. Then I created a folder in my webroot and let Apache point to it. After that, I downloaded the installation file via composer to the folder. and surf to the domain in the browser and get routed to the installation site just as expected. I can progress without errors (just a warning about clean URLs, but the installation is just for testing automation scripts, so no matter about UX) until the creation of the database. There I typed in the name of the database and the SQL credentials. Then I click on "Create and Continue" but after the site is loading a while, it stays on the site and I can not progress. When I refresh the site i get a long error message.

> Error
> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

When I typed the domain in the browser again, I get a blank site with the same error. I tried to create the database before I start the installer, tried if the installer is creating on its own, the error does not change.

Maybe it has something to do with the VM setup?
How can I setup the VM to install Drupal?

There are two exceptions in the webserver:

> Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException: Configuration objects provided by standard have unmet dependencies: block_content.type.basic (block_content), comment.type.comment (comment), [a row of unmet dependency exceptions, all from ConfigInstaller.php and paths within the folder I created]

(It seemed like a attempt to create database tables that is going wrong.)

Comment: Hello. Errors like that are logged by the web server. Find out what the error is.

Comment: I strongly suggest Lando or DDEV if this is for development purposes.

Comment: @cilefen Thanks for the suggestion, i check it out.

Answer (score 1):

This error often occurs when `max_allowed_packet` has not been set according to the [Drupal database requirements](https://www.drupal.org/node/259580).